# How to load a dataset (.rs) which contains nodes and their RSSI in cooja simulator

Tags: contiki, rssi, cooja

I have a dataset with extension (.rs) this data set contain : creation of nodes, and variation of links characteristics over time, this is a small example of my dataset:

```
motetype;Client
motetype;Server;1.0
39000;baserssi;20.0;-97
41000;baserssi;1.0;-93
48000;baserssi;8.0;-94
51000;baserssi;7.0;-94
56000;baserssi;10.0;-94
63000;baserssi;9.0;-98
65000;baserssi;6.0;-97
67000;baserssi;3.0;-96
74000;baserssi;5.0;-96
0;addnode;20.0
0;addnode;1.0
108000;setedge;20.0;1.0;75,000000;-87;91
0;addnode;3.0
108000;setedge;20.0;3.0;62,500000;-41;104
108000;baserssi;20.0;-97
112000;setedge;1.0;20.0;50,000000;-91;87
0;addnode;8.0
112000;setedge;1.0;8.0;87,500000;-77;106
112000;setedge;1.0;3.0;62,500000;-89;101
112000;baserssi;1.0;-93
116000;setedge;8.0;1.0;87,500000;-77;107
0;addnode;6.0
116000;setedge;8.0;6.0;62,500000;-86;103
0;addnode;9.0
```

I want to create a simulation in cooja using this network topology ( which is in my dataset) with DGRM (Directed Graph Radio Medium) configuration.

I would to ask how can I load it in cooja simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the RealSim plugin to the Cooja. Please get the source code and read the instructions here: https://github.com/cmorty/realsim/tree/master/cooja-plugin